# При повторном выполнение запроса не отлавливается исключение

Tags: android, rxjava

Создаю запрос вот таким образом. Если после того, как вызвался showError(). вызвать doRequest() еще раз, то ошибка не отловится и все упадет. Пробовал задавать глобальный error хэндлер. Но это не помогает.

```
private void doRequest() {
    Subscription subscription = AppObservable.bindFragment(this, Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Object>> subscriber) {
            //тут происходят какие-то сетевые запросы
            //если все плохо, то кидается исключение
            //это исключение и не отлавливается при повторном выполнении этого кода
            subscriber.onNext(new ArrayList<>());
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }))
            .flatMap(getStringSelector(), getMapFunction())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                    if (aBoolean) {
                        showOk();
                    }
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    showError();
                }
            });

    CompositeSubscription subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    subscriptions.add(subscription);
}
    @NotNull
    private Func2<List<Object>, List<String>, Boolean> getMapFunction() {
        return new Func2<List<Object>, List<String>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(List<Object> objects, List<String> stringList) {
                if (objects.size() == 0 || stringList.size() == 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("");
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    @NotNull
    private Func1<List<Object>, Observable<List<String>>> getStringSelector() {
        return new Func1<List<Object>, Observable<List<String>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<String>> call(List<Object> objects) {
                if (objects.size() == 0) {
                    return Observable.error(new Exception("some text"));
                }
                return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<String>> subscriber) {
                        subscriber.onNext(new ArrayList<String>());
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

**UPD:** лог ошибки. Собственно исключение ***Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:***  должно быть отловлено и отлавливается при первом вызове

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:201)
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.innerError(OperatorMerge.java:457)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:432)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMapPair$2.onError(OperatorMapPair.java:74)
            at rx.android.app.OperatorConditionalBinding$1.onError(OperatorConditionalBinding.java:69)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:183)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:159)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred.
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:201)
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.innerError(OperatorMerge.java:457)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:432)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMapPair$2.onError(OperatorMapPair.java:74)
            at rx.android.app.OperatorConditionalBinding$1.onError(OperatorConditionalBinding.java:69)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:183)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:159)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
            at com.flurry.sdk.bx.uncaughtException(SourceFile:325)
            at com.flurry.sdk.eq.a(SourceFile:90)
            at com.flurry.sdk.eq.a(SourceFile:19)
            at com.flurry.sdk.eq$a.uncaughtException(SourceFile:106)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:66)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 11 path $[0].name
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.invoke(RestAdapter.java:265)
            at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:55)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 11 path $[0].name
            at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:67)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.invoke(RestAdapter.java:265)
            at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:55)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 11 path $[0].name
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFac
```

Comment: Насколько я помню Rх, если внутри случается исключение, то дальнейшая энумерация прекращается. То есть после срабатывания `onError` больше ничего не происходит, при попытке добавить новое событие всё равно остаётся статус ошибки. Нужно пересоздавать `Observable` (или подавлять ошибку как-то ещё). Может, у вас эта проблема?

Comment: @VladD да, я тоже так думал. Но ведь первый раз срабатывает. И ошибка JsonSyntaxException отлавливается. В методе showError() просто отображается кнопка "повторить" и по нажатию на нее вызывается снова метод doRequest()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема решена. Сначала я обновил rxJava до последней на текущей момент версии

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.11'
```

после этого логи стали более осмысленными и там да, стало ясно, что кидается неотлавливаемое исключение. 
Далее добавил вызов для ошибки и все. Странность в том, что перед написанием поста, я пробовал сделать так, но это не работало.

```
.onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends Boolean> call(Throwable throwable) {
                return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                        subscriber.onNext(false);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

А ошибка может произойти в сетевом запросе, но обработчика ошибки:

```
Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Object>> subscriber) {
        //тут происходят какие-то сетевые запросы
        //если все плохо, то кидается исключение
        //это исключение и не отлавливается при повторном выполнении этого кода
        subscriber.onNext(new ArrayList<>());
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}))
```

Где код subscriber.onError(Throwable e)?

Comment: он не нужен. кинутое исключение должно прийти в Action1<Throwable>() которе инициализируется в методе subscribe

Comment: Я не так давно начал изучать rxJava, но мне кажется(скорее всего) здесь идет не соответствие потоков(Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError). Ошибку уходит в др поток который не может ее обработать и вернуть.
AppObservable.bindFragment эта штука делает observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()). Можно попробовать добавить перед subscribe, subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
Я такую ошибку получал именно тогда, когда подписка и выполнение были в разных потоках.